# How to detect if errno_t is defined?

Tags: c++, typedef, errno

I'm compiling code using gcc that comes from Visual C++ 2008. The code is using errno_t, but in some versions of gcc headers including `<errno.h>` doesn't define the type. How do I detect if the type is defined? Is there a define that signals that the type was defined? In the case it isn't defined I'd like to provide the typedef to let the code compile correctly on all platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check for a typedef the way you can for a macro, so this is a bit on the tricky side. If you're using `autoconf`, [this patch](http://www.mail-archive.com/freeipa-devel@redhat.com/msg00086.html) shows the minimum changes that you need to have autoconf check for the presence of `errno_t` and define it if it's missing (the typedef would be placed in a file that includes your generated `config.h` and is included by all files that need `errno_t`). If you're not using `autoconf` you need to come up with some way to do the same thing within your build system, or a very clever set of tests against compiler version macros.

Comment: thanks. I don't have autoconf available, so I guess I have to go with compiler version macro checks...

Comment: Alex's answer, not this one, is the correct answer. `errno_t` should never be used for anything because the type of `errno` is specified as `int`.

Comment: People may be interested in using `errno_t` because it was recommended by CERT. https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/DCL09-C.+Declare+functions+that+return+errno+with+a+return+type+of+errno_t

Comment: Yet another nonsensical recommendation from CERT.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft's `errno_t` is redundant. `errno` is defined by the ISO C standard to be a modifiable lvalue of type `int`. If your code needs to store `errno` values, then you should put them into an `int`.

Do a global search and replace `s/errno_t/int/` and you're done.

**Edit:** Also, you shouldn't be providing a `typedef int errno_t` in your code, because all names that end with `_t` are reserved.

Comment: "all names that end with `_t` are reserved." Is that so? Where is this declared?

Comment: sbi: Hmm, I didn't have a ready answer, so I've done a bit of research. The _t namespace is widely described as being "reserved by POSIX", but I've not found anything to that effect in the POSIX spec. The best source is from glibc: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html. I think it boils down to the fact that POSIX, or ISO C may define new _t names, so in many people's opinion they are best avoided in application code.

Comment: C99 enumerates the types defined in the standard headers and warns that "typedef names beginning with `int` or `uint` and ending with `_t` may be added" to `stdint.h` but it doesn't embargo `*_t` entirely.

Comment: Here's the citation for POSIX reserving `_t`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02

Answer (score 0):

This is typically the case where [GNU autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) comes to the rescue. Basically autoconf will generate a configure script that can detect various system-dependent features such as whether this type exists and how it is defined. You then include the generated C header file within your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which versions of GCC are giving you trouble, you can test for them. You can check for versions of GCC using something like:

```
  #if __GNUC__ == 3
  ...
  #else
  ...
  #endif
```